# How do you do a HMSET in C# using the StackExchange redis library?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to do an HMSET using the Stack Exchange Redis library I but cannot figure out how. I know the differences between HSET and HMSET and I know how to use HSET so why can't I HMSET? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please post your first attempt at making this work. It's far harder to help out when we don't know what specifically is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it does support HMSET just by looking at the [tests for the source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/2a5c4f7a01815abe40d150263a1adf4f378c06b0/tests/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/Hashes.cs#L502):

```
var data = new HashEntry[] {
    new HashEntry("foo", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc")),
    new HashEntry("bar", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("def"))
};
conn.HashSetAsync(hashkey, data).ForAwait();
```